# Securely reward a Facebook wall post

Tags: facebook, security

We're developing a social game on Facebook from which players can share posts on their wall. Now we want to reward them for that with in-game currency.

Of course, this should not provide an opening for hackers to generate infinite funds, but since the posting happens entirely client side, they could so by repeatedly telling our server "I have posted", though they haven't. Unless we add countermeasures.

- Can our server check with Facebook whether a post was really made?
- Can we attach data to a wallpost, like a cryptographic signature generated by our server?
- If not, we need to limit the currency a hacker can acquire with some kind of flood control. Tips there?

Answer (score 1):

> We're developing a social game on Facebook from which players can share posts on their wall. Now we want to reward them for that with in-game currency.

I think that’d be a violoation of [Facebook Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/):

> IV. Application Integration Points
>
> 1. You must not incentivize users to use (or gate content behind the use of) Facebook social channels, or imply that an incentive is directly tied to the use of our channels.

Comment: Ah, I'll notify the rest of the team. However, that means you also cannot reward players for inviting new players, which many games seem to be doing.

Comment: Oh, they have an exception for that: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/examples_and_explanations/Rewarding_Users/

Answer (score 0):

The callback you get after using the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) will return to you a `post_id`.  You can store that `post_id` in your database along with a flag indicating that you have already rewarded the user for that specific post. This way you can "reward" users once per post by testing the existence of that `post_id` + flag in your database.

Comment: A hacker could send any random ID though, we'd have to check with Facebook whether the post exists and is from our game.